# Discord.js online member count does not update instantly

Tags: discord, discord.js

I use following code to get online member count every 1 sec,

`guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'online' && !member.user.bot).size;`

It is not updated the channel name with member count instantly when I m hosting my bot on Heroku, but I run my bot on a local pc it will update the channel name instantly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Updating a channel name *every second* is API Abuse, your client may be suspended from using the Discord API

Comment: I only update when the old online member count and new member count are different.
what is the best way to do this?

Comment: As stated above, it's never a good idea to change a channel name everytime someone comes online or offline. Discord will report your bot as API spam and remove your account off the developer program permantly. Instead, maybe do something like how many people are in your server.

Comment: @Tyler2P But I see verified public discord bots giving this feature as a premium feature that why I try to build that functionality in my own private discord bot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using guild.members.**cache**, information about user presence won't be up-to-date (cache only updates sometimes so it doesn't have to bother the API server that much).

Here you can use the `presenceUpdate` event:

```
// you could run this once to get the initial number of online users
var onlineCount = guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'online' && !member.user.bot).size;

// and only change the counter if there's a change
client.on("presenceUpdate", (old, new) => {
  if(!new.user.bot && old.status != new.status){
    if(new.status === "online"){onlineCount++;}
    if(old.status === "online"){onlineCount--;}
  }
});
```

Note: You'll probably need to enable 'Presence intent' in 'Privileged Gateway Intents' in your bot's settings page for this to work.
(https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Comment: I use an event handler how I do this?

Comment: @Nelusha I'm not sure I understood your question correctly. If you mean that you're used to using `.addEventListener` then it's the same as `.on`.

Comment: @Nelusha
Using event handlers is simple: just call `.on` function on an object that supports it (in this case it's the Client object) with 2 parameters: name of the event, callback - the function you want to execute when the event triggers.
You can browse all methods and events in Discord.js documentation: [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

Comment: To get the initial member count the code should be run inside the 'ready' event then how I access that initial count inside 'presenceUpdate' event. I use separate files for each event.

Comment: @Nelusha If you already have those features intergrated, it should be quite simple to add one more. If you don't know how, I suggest you go out and learn the language before asking others to create your own projects.